# store folder is missing inside src folder in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a past project with vue and I had a folder/file called `src/store/index.js` by default installation. The `router` folder is also missing. My current version now is `v2.6.12`. Is there any changes in folder and file structure?

**Screenshot of current structure**

[image]

Comment: did you create the project using `vue create project-name` of vue cli?

Comment: No. just normal installation

Comment: what do you mean by normal installation? could you provide the steps?

Comment: I did npm install vue

Comment: but that doesn't bootstrap any structure, it only add vue dependency

Comment: What should I do? Sorry Im new to vuejs

Comment: please run `vue --version` in command line/terminal and give me the output

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim `@vue/cli 4.5.6`

Comment: I recommend to use `vue create project-name` then follow the steps which are clear

Comment: Yea, will do that and just transfer all my progress. Thanks man